# Use of that in "The idea that war is obsolescent may seem..."

Tags: word-usage, conjunctions, relative-clauses

> The idea that war is obsolescent may seem preposterously utopian.

As far as I understood “that” in this sentence is not relative clauses. Then what does it mean? And can I use a phrase or a word after “that” like:

> The grammar structure (that) “want someone to do something”...
>
> The word (that) jurassic means the periods between the Triassic and Cretaceous.

Comment: We're less *likely* to omit ***that*** in your first cited context than in, say, ***I think** [that] war is obsolete*, but I'd say [that] syntactically it's essentially the same "optional ***that***". Which is *not* the case in your final example (where including ***that*** is simply "ungrammatical").

Comment: You do know the difference between obsolete and obsolescent?

Answer (score 2):

> The idea [that war is obsolescent] may seem preposterously utopian.

*That war is obsolescent* is a [declarative content clause](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_clause#Declarative_content_clauses). It says what the *contents* of that idea are, as it were. Content clauses are also called noun clauses.

> The sad truth [that there aren’t many honest people in the world] seems to be true.

The bracketed clause is a content clause: it gives the contents of the sad truth; it says what that truth is. *The sad truth*, just like *the idea* in the previous example, simply describes the nature of the message contained in the content clause: it says whether the message is an idea, a fact, a truth, and so on. The clause is the message itself.

---

Here is an example of a relative clause:

> The idea [that I'm presenting in this letter] is only a few hours old.

The bracketed clause describes the idea, but it does not say what that idea is. It does not say what the contents of that idea are. It merely gives some information related to it. The relative pronoun *that* in this sentence functions as the object of the verb *presenting*. It can be omitted:

> The idea [I'm presenting in this letter] is only a few hours old.

When *that* is the subject of the clause, it is obligatory:

> The idea [that was popular in most aerodynamic circles] was the concept of the ornithopter.

Again, the bracketed clause is a relative one since it merely describes the noun. The pronoun *that* is not optional here, however.

---

One common expression that uses the same pattern as in your example is *the fact that*:

> The fact [that he had left] proved to me that everything he'd said was true.
>
> The fact [that quick results are unlikely] is no excuse for delay.

In content clauses of this type, *that* is often left in, although it is still optional:

> The fact [we didn’t win when we were so close] is very disappointing.
>
> The idea [he's willing to have a debate] is a sign of weakness.

Comment: The sad truth that there aren’t many honest people in the world seems to be true. In this sentence is “that there aren’t honest people in the world “used as relative clauses? Or used as noun clauses?

Comment: @Foreignstudent *The sad truth [that there aren’t many honest people in the world] seems to be true.* It's a relative clause.

Comment: ***What** sad truth?,*  *Oh - **that** sad truth!*

Comment: @Foreignstudent No, it's not a relative clause (nor are any of athonum's examples) but a declarative content clause functioning as complement of "idea". Relative clauses function as modifiers and typically have a relative pronoun which has a noun phrase as antecedent.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you. I've rewritten my answer. Could you please check it?